# How to add CPT category in navigation menu automatically in WP?

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic, menu, categories

I’ve created custom post type “PRODUCT”. What I need is whenever I add product with different category then the newly added category should automatically be added on my navigation menu [not repeated category]. Let us say if I add new product with a category “HEALTH” then this newly added category should appear on my navigation menu and should list all products of this category. But if I add another product on same category [HEALTH] then it shouldn’t be added on menu. Just new categories should be added. I hope I made my question clear.

```
PRODUCT
 Health
 Beauty
```

I can do it manually by going to appearance>menu but I want it to be added automatically to my navigation menu.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that.you have to specify taxonomy in get_terms('') function

```
<?php

$taxonomy = 'portfolio_categories';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>"><?php echo $term->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif;?>

?>
```